# Generated Javascript from Coffeescript is not lint ready? -> Throws Lint Error in Yeoman / Grunt

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, yeoman

at the moment i am trying to improve my workflow for building an web-app.
With Yeoman installed, the command "grunt" gives me a good way to combine and minify my javascript files. 
My main.js file gets generated from a lot of coffeescript files, which i'm doing manually before. I don't use the integrated way of compiling coffeescript because of file dependencies. (this is ok)

**But here's the problem:**
when i now trying to run "grunt" it gives me "lint" errors from my generated js file like:

```
line 3   col 3    Missing "use strict" statement.
line 3   col 3    Expected 'var' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
line 4   col 102  Expected '{' and instead saw 'child'.
line 4   col 233  A constructor name should start with an uppercase letter.

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

if i --force it to continue, the main.js in the outcoming dest folder is still empty

What can i do? **I thought that compiled coffeescript is "lint ready" javascript?**

To compile my coffeescript files i use "rehab":
https://www.npmjs.org/package/rehab

which provides me this Cakefile:

```
{exec, spawn} = require 'child_process'
Rehab = require 'rehab'

build = ->
      console.log "Building project from src/*.coffee to app/scripts/main.js"

      files = new Rehab().process 'src'
      files = files.join " "

      join_to_single_file = "--join app/scripts/main.js"
      compile_from_files = "--compile #{files}"

      exec "coffee #{join_to_single_file} #{compile_from_files}", (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        throw err if err

task 'build', 'Build coffee2js using Rehab', sbuild = ->
  build()
```

UPDATE:

If I understand correctly my main.js file will never passing jshint, so i have to remove the checking from yeoman / grunt to go further? I removed this line from my gruntfile.js:

```
// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
          // removed  '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
```

Now i got no errors if running "grunt", but my output in dest folder contains still an empty main.js :(

Comment: There’s no point in lint-checking compiled CoffeeScript. You can adjust your settings to fit what CoffeeScript produces, but it doesn’t get you anywhere, because CoffeeScript *does* always produce code to fit that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the Coffeescript team cares about having its generated code pass jslint. (Or they used to, but that time has passed). See [JavaScript Lint warnings caused by default argument values](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2500) bug on the Coffeescript Github repo.

You could use [coffeelint](http://www.coffeelint.org/) to check your code (there's even a [Grunt module](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-coffeelint)).

However, Coffeelint checks several things but misses things that you may expect if you're expecting jslint style checks. (Coffeelint is more a stylistic checker).

In a large Coffeescript project I've taken to using both coffeelint **and** [coffee-jshint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coffee-jshint). js**hint** makes more pragmatic choices about Javascript style (and has an easier interface to turn everything off), which jives more with the Javascript that Coffeescript produces. The coffee-jshint package passes the right parameters to jshint to not be too strict with the machine generated code.